# Override JavaScript conditional statement

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I know it is possible to override functions in JS, however is it possible to override implementation of conditional statements like ''if''.

**Update** As asked by some comments, I am building a Chrome extension goal is to log and edit when ever if statement is executed on a web page.

Comment: No. // more characters to reach minimum comment length

Comment: there is no way to refer to them to change them, so you can't

Comment: Do you mean something that would redefine how all `if` statements work?

Comment: Show us an example of the specific code and describe what you want to happen.  "override a conditional" is not exactly a clear statement.  Why not just edit the code as desired in your editor?

Comment: You most likely will want to write a transformer (using a JS parsers such as esprima) to rewrite the if statements to include instrumentation logic.

Comment: @torazaburo can you provide further details on it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't override conditionals directly.

If you want, you can wrap them in a function and then override the function, which might accomplish what you want.